# loc command with pandas failing to filter column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to run loc command on a column to filter for certrain entries but when doing a df.shape after its showing no rows in the dataframe

[image]

```
df1 = df[df['spindle'] == '2']
print(df1.shape)
```

Im not sure if the issue is to do with spaces in the spindle column or not but unsure how to resolve it...

Comment: try printing `df.info()`, it seems like `spindle` column is likely to be a numerical value, not a string (2, not '2')

Comment: First it the code you used doesn't actually use `.loc`, but I guess that shouldn't matter for this question. Could it be the data type? You are filtering to only rows where the value of the "spindle" column is equal to 2 (string dtype). It this correct? 
If it is an int you would just do `df1 = df[df['spindle'] == 2]`

Comment: Yea changing from a string to a numerical value fixed it. Thank you